# Nagios - Possible to Create Dependancy tree for service with a parent host?

Tags: linux, nagios

In Nagios, assume the following scenario: you have 3 hosts, A B and C each with services 1-3, and having host B as a parent host to host C with A being at the same level as B.

Is it possible to;
a) When scheduling downtime for host A, also have downtime scheduled for all services on that host?
b) When downtime occurs, unexpected or otherwise on host B, have all service on host C be considered down also without alerts or notifications, like the host itself is?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to both questions is "no".  There are several scripts floating around to do (a), but Nagios does not put downtime on a hosts services when it is on the host.  However, Nagios will not notify for services while the host is down, it's when the host comes back up and services are still down that you will get notifications.  As for (b), you can do this by putting dependencies between the services, but you can't have services depend on a host to my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

In Nagios 3, (a) is the default behaviour.  I think that (b) is also how things work in Nagios 3, although I haven't personally tested that.

Comment: Hmm, I will need to go back and double check everything, I seem to be getting different behaviour with Nagios 3. I went back and looked for scenario a, and it is supposed to be the default behaviour for Nagios 3. For b, it looks like the service_dependency option allows for hostnames - at least it doesn't error when nagios loads. I still need to do some furhter checking.